# How to filter a list of maps using an external variable

Tags: karate

I have a list of maps like this:

```
[
  {
     "name": "Marco",
     "email": "marco@gmail.com",
     "age": 20
  }, {
     "name": "Polo",
     "email": "polo@gmail.com",
     "age": 25
  }   
]
```

And I want to return only the entry whose email is a specific one, like polo@gmail.com
I'll normally filter like this:

```
 * def filter_func = function(x){ return x.email == "polo@gmail.com" }
 * def list = response
 * def filtered = karate.filter(list, filter_func)
```

But the email have to be a variable, because first I create a random account, then I get the list of accounts and have to check that the account was added and will use it's other parameters later, like the age.

Is there any way to use the karate filter function with an external variable, or another strategy?
The variable usage would be like this(not working example):

```
 * def email = "polo@gmail.com"
 * def filter_func = function(x, e){ return x.email == e }
 * def list = response
 * def filtered = karate.filter(list, email, filter_func)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, just simple JS:

```
* def email = "polo@gmail.com"
* def fun = function(x){ return x.email == email }
* def filtered = karate.filter(response, fun)
* print filtered
```

Since `fun` was declared *after* `email` the variable reference works.

In some rare cases, if the function was declared earlier - e.g. when you want to achieve re-use of code, note that you can always use `karate.get(name)` to get the "currently existing" variable value by variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found out I can just reference the variable inside the function, like:

```
 * def email = "polo@gmail.com"
 * def filter_func = function(x){ return x.email == email }
 * def list = response
 * def filtered = karate.filter(list, filter_func)
```