# json filter based assertion in karate feature file returns error 'Expected character: ) ==> expected: <0> but was: <1>'

Tags: json, filter, contains, karate, assertion

I have a working json filter that extracts a value from a key field from which I need to do a contains assertion for since there will be more than 1 key/value pair.

```
background
* def capturedBy = '123456'

scenario xyz

Given url
When get
Then status 200
And match $[*].ind.this.[(@.urn='urn:com.owe:mea:nickel:veryrichdude:3336789012:license:86761267')].By contains [#(capturedBy)]
```

I am getting an error message on the below assertion: "Expected character: ) # ==> expected: <0> but was: <1>"

Any ideas what could be the cause of this?

I've also tried the text value directly in the assertion like:
"Given When Then 200 And match $[*].ind.this.[(@.urn='urn:com.owe:mea:nickel:veryrichdude:3336789012:license:86761267')].By contains '123456' with same error.

I tried escaping the "(" & ")" with no success.

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: besides the linked answer, another tip - sometimes the `karate.filter()` api is a lot easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62873484/143475